# change the default message on upload file cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp I want to upload a file on a form entry, e.g. a resume to upload and also form entry of people's names, addresses etc. The problem is when I upload a file I get the message after the file is uploaded 'no file selected'. The function works but this message is confusing for the user as I want the name of the file displayed instead of 'no file selected'.

EDIT
Next to the button Browse, the label appears 'No file Selected'. How do I suppress/alter this message?

UPDATE: Found a workaround answer which might not be the best solution.

### View

```
echo $this->Form->input('reason', array('label' => 'Reason for Cancellation', 'style'=> "width:30%",'value'=>$reason));
echo __('Upload Attachment');
echo $this->Form->input('resume_file', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Upload', array('name'=>'upload'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

### Controller

```
public function uploadfile() {
$reason=null;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (isset($this->request->data['upload'])) {
                $reason=$this->request->data['Resume']['reason'];
                if ($this->attachmentupload() && $this->Resume->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The attachment has been saved'), 'flash_success');
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The attachment could not be saved. Please, try again.'),'flash_alert');
                }
        }
    }
}


public function attachmentupload() {

    $file = $this->request->data['Resume']['resume_file'];
    $resume_org_filename = $file['name'];
    $resume_filename = $file['name'];

    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        // Code to check if file with the same name exists. If it exists - add n towards the end
        $t = 0;
        $url = APP.'Resumes'.DS.$resume_filename;

        while(file_exists($url)) {
            $resume_filename = substr($resume_filename,0, strpos($resume_filename, '.'))."_$t".strstr($resume_filename, '.');
            $url = APP.'Resumes'.DS.$resume_filename;
            $t++;
        }

        // Set the parameters
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url)) {
            $this->request->data['Resume']['tutor_id'] = -1;
            $this->request->data['Resume']['student_id'] = -1;
            $this->request->data['Resume']['url'] = $url ;
            $this->request->data['Resume']['resume_filename'] = $resume_filename;
            $this->request->data['Resume']['resume_org_filename'] = $resume_org_filename;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to suppress the label and add the element in a table/div with a label